# Is there a way of inheriting Hibernate's @Where annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate

We have a DB table `user` that evolved quite a bit and we don't want to load legacy users into the app. Legacy user is identified by `user_type` column.

If I use following mapping then everything works as expected:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Where("user_type = 2") // 1 is legacy
class User {

    @Column(name="user_type")
    int type;
}
```

I need to map `user` table multiple times and I want to stay **DRY**. So I thought I can extract `@Where` bit to a super class and inherit it like so:

```
@Where("type = 2") // 1 is legacy
abstract class BaseUser {   
}

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
class User extends BaseUser {
}
```

I have a following test (I hope it's self-explanatory enough) that fails though:

```
@Test
@DbUnitData("legacy_user.xml") // populates DB with 1 user (id=1) with type=1
public void shouldNotGetLegacyUser() {
    assertThat(em.find(User.class, 1L)).isNull();
}
```

Is there a way of inheriting a class with Hibernate's `@Where` annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are really looking for is not the @Where but the @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorValue. These annotations allow you to map two @Entity objects to the same table based on a @DiscriminatorColumn.

The Hibernate manual has a paragraph on it:
[Mapping inheritance](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168)

You would basically create a superclass, BaseUser and two Sub classes, LegacyUser and User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COM_ORDER")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "COM_ORDER_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public class BaseUser {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    <Enter your generic columns here, you do not need to add the user_type column>
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
public class LegacyUser extends BaseUser {
    <Enter your legacy specific fields here>
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class LatestUser extends BaseUser {
    <Enter your new and improved user fields here>
}
```

With this setup, you can easliy expand the number of user types by creating new classes which extend the BaseUser class. You need to keep in mind that the fields on the actual table can only be not-null for fields in the BaseUser class. Fields in the UserType related classes should always be nullable in the database since they will only ever be used by a specific user type.

> Edit:
>   I've edit the example to conform to the setup I'm currently using in my own project. This setup works fine for me.

Comment: This does not work for me. At first it was complaining about the missing ID in `BaseUser` so I added one. Now it is complaining about this: `org.hibernate.mapping.SingleTableSubclass cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass`

Comment: right, so I found the issue - it appears that I *can't* map the discriminator column itself in child class ...